# One writer + multiple readers channel in rust std

Tags: rust

I want to find a channel implementation of channel like [this](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/mpsc/fn.sync_channel.html), but with inversed count of readers and writers, i.e. only one allowed writer with infinite number of readers. Is it exists or i need to write it manually?

Comment: When the producer sends a message, should all the readers receive it or only one of them (e.g. the first to try to read)?

Comment: @Jmb all readers should receive it

Answer (score 0):

The documentation page you linked to calls this kind of channels "mpsc", which stands for Multiple Producer, Single Consumer. The converse is therefore Single Producer, Multiple Consumer. Googling "rust spmc channel" leads to [what you are looking for](https://docs.rs/spmc/latest/spmc/) as the very first result.